# Google document AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I have raised a request for Google invoice parser last week, but haven't received any response from them. Does anyone has experience in getting access from google? or any contact?

Comment: Please clarify if your question is about Document AI or about getting in touch with Google? Would you like to share how exactly have you raised a request with Google?

Comment: I have got the access of document AI which has free trail for form parse but I require Invoice parser access as well which I raised in Google cloud platform>Document AI>Create processor>Invoice parser. When you click on invoice parser it takes to request page.

Comment: Could you please rephrase the original post to better understand if your issue is about Invoice parser, or about getting in contact with Google.

Comment: If your question is about getting in contact with Google, it shouldn't be posted here. See more about on-topic questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

With API calls you can

- Either get immediately the result in a [Document structure if your file is small](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/invoice-parser#online-process)
- Or get the [name of the processing job if your file is large](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/invoice-parser#batch-process). Then you have to request periodically the job name to check the status and get the result

Answer (score 1):

I got a response for the invoice parser in about a month, I think it depends on how many requests they have and after the recent web presentation of their AI api's requests grew. Just give it some more time.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30247060)